# How to get a list of in-app purchases from the Apple server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios-4.2

I am developing an iPhone app which provides in-app purchases. However, after creating a product ID for an in-app purchase, I must manually update the list in either the client, or on a custom server. This seems a little odd.

Is their any web service that I can use to directly communicate with Apple's server in order to get a list of registered product IDs dynamically?

Or is there an API that my iPhone client can use to communicate with StoreKit to get the list of registered product IDs from Apple's server?

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't :

From the In App purchase Programming Guide

> Apple recommends you retrieve product
>   identifiers from your server, rather
>   than including them in a property
>   list. This gives you the flexibility
>   to add new products without updating
>   your application.

You can find a similar answer here :

[StoreKit to return all product IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844456/storekit-to-return-all-product-ids)

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: I have seen an app which has product categories on the left hand side of table and products under each category. How to get them, are they included in server as well along with products??